# Can someone help implement gravity and running animation into my pygame code?

Tags: python, pygame, gravity

I'm making Mario with pygame for my class assessment this school term and am sorta new to pygame, i can't find anywhere how to properly implement gravity into my game, so when mario jumps, he comes back down. My second problem is trying to make a running animation, i want Mario to flick through pictures as he moves left and right in the order; 1, 2, 3, 2 (and over and over). If someone could help it would be great!

```
import pygame

import time

import random


pygame.init()


display_width = 800
display_height = 600
mario_width = 55

blue = (77, 240, 255)
green = (0, 186, 43)
ground_colour = (186, 150, 97)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Super Italiano Bros")

direction = 'right'
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
cloudImg = pygame.image.load('Cloud.png')


rightMarioImg = pygame.image.load('MarioRight.png')
rightMarioImg2 = pygame.image.load("MarioRight2.png")
rightMarioImg3 = pygame.image.load("MarioRight3.png")

leftMarioImg = pygame.image.load('MarioLeft.png')
leftMarioImg2 = pygame.image.load('MarioLeft2.png')
leftMarioImg3 = pygame.image.load('MarioLeft3.png')

def marioRight(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(rightMarioImg, (x,y))

def marioLeft(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(leftMarioImg, (x,y))

def cloud(x_cloud,y_cloud):
    gameDisplay.blit(cloudImg, (x_cloud,y_cloud))

def cloud_two(x_cloud_two,y_cloud_two):
    gameDisplay.blit(cloudImg, (x_cloud_two,y_cloud_two))       

def game_loop():
    global direction

    x = (320)
    y = (360)

    x_cloud = (-200)
    y_cloud = (-220)

    x_cloud_two = (200)
    y_cloud_two = (-170)

    x_change = (0)
    y_change = (0)

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            print(event)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -5
                direction = 'left'
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5
                direction = 'right'
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change = -60
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                x_change = 0
                y_change = 60

        x += x_change
        y += y_change

        if x <= 0:
            x = 0
        if y <= 300:
            y = 300
        if y >= 360:
            y = 360
            
        gameDisplay.fill(blue)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ground_colour, (0,500,800,500))
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, green, (0, 470, 800, 30))
        cloud(x_cloud,y_cloud)
        cloud_two(x_cloud_two,y_cloud_two)

        if direction == 'right':
            marioRight(x,y)
        else:
            marioLeft(x,y)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Could you somehow provide the images so that the example is runable?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed some issues and did a lot of code styling. When you press the up key he jumps a fixed amount and when you release it he goes back to the ground level. Now it animates itself. The image is changed every loop, which is probably super fast, so you will probably only want to increase the state every a certain amount of frames.

Summary of what I changed:

1. Imports are usually grouped in three different blocks (divided by a single blank line) and ordered alphabetically:

   1. The first block contains all standard library imports
   2. The second block contains third party libraries
   3. The third block contains local imports to other files in this project
2. A file should have 0 not used imports
3. Function and variable names in python follow snake case notation: `my_variable` and `my_function`. "Constants" are written in snake upper case: `MY_CONSTANT`. Classes use camel case: `MyClass`.
4. `dict`s and `list`s allow you to store data in a more organized way. For example, we can have a `MARIO_IMGS` `dict` of `list`s that store all the mario images so they can be accessed like `MARIO_IMGS['right'][0]` (the first image is index 0 as lists start counting by 0).
5. Try to avoid global variables, I moved the variables that were only needed inside the loop to the `game_loop` function and the remaining top level statements that were not definitions isnide a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block that runs whenever this script is launched but not when this scrip is imported.
6. Functions are meant to be reused, having `cloud`and `cloud_two` functions that do exactly the same makes no sense. Call `cloud(x_cloud, y_cloud)` and then `cloud(x_cloud_two, y_cloud_two)`.
7. Do not use unneeded brackets if they do not provide clarity, for example: `x = (320)` should be `x = 320`
8. You had a indentation error where you process events outside the event loop, so only the last event would be processed (except for exiting, that part was inside the loop so every event would be checked against `pygame.QUIT`)
9. Lines should be 80 chars or lower.
10. `quit()` at the end of a python file is not needed. `quit()` is mostly used to close the python interpreter from a terminal window.

```py
import pygame

# Window width and height in px
DISPLAY_SIZE = (800, 600)
# Window title
TITLE = "Super Italiano Bros"

# Predefined colors
BLUE = (77, 240, 255)
GREEN = (0, 186, 43)
GROUND_COLOR = (186, 150, 97)

# Images
MARIO_IMGS = {
    'right': [
        pygame.image.load('MarioRight.png'),
        pygame.image.load("MarioRight2.png"),
        pygame.image.load("MarioRight3.png"),
        pygame.image.load("MarioRight2.png"),
    ],
    'left': [
        pygame.image.load('MarioLeft.png'),
        pygame.image.load('MarioLeft2.png'),
        pygame.image.load('MarioLeft3.png'),
        pygame.image.load('MarioLeft2.png'),
    ]
}
CLOUD_IMG = pygame.image.load('Cloud.png')
MAX_STATES = min(map(len, MARIO_IMGS.values()))  # 3


def draw_mario(x, y, direction='right', state=0):
    screen.blit(MARIO_IMGS[direction][state], (x, y))


def draw_cloud(x_cloud, y_cloud):
    screen.blit(CLOUD_IMG, (x_cloud, y_cloud))


def game_loop():
    # Mario position
    x = 320
    y = 360
    x_change = 0
    state = 0
    direction = 'right'

    # Cloud positions
    x_cloud = -200
    y_cloud = -220
    x_cloud_two = 200
    y_cloud_two = -170

    # Clock used to limit the FPS
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    game_exit = False
    while not game_exit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_exit = True
            print(event)

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                    direction = 'left'
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5
                    direction = 'right'
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y = 300
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    game_exit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y = 360

        x += x_change

        if x < 0:
            x = 0
        elif x > DISPLAY_SIZE[0]:
            x = DISPLAY_SIZE[0]

        screen.fill(BLUE)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GROUND_COLOR, (0, 500, 800, 500))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, (0, 470, 800, 30))
        draw_cloud(x_cloud, y_cloud)
        draw_cloud(x_cloud_two, y_cloud_two)

        draw_mario(x, y, direction, state)
        # Increase the state to animate Mario
        state += 1
        state %= MAX_STATES  # Start back from 0 if we have reached the end

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY_SIZE)
    pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)
    game_loop()

    pygame.quit()
```

You should probably change your mario and cloud to `Sprite`s. An `Sprite` is a class that has a `rect` and an `image` attributes that define how they are drawn, and then instead of using `screen.blit(IMAGE, POSITION)` you just tell pygame to draw the sprite and he will use those two attributes to draw the desired `image` at the position of the `rect`.

Comment: Holy crap thank you so so much! this is a ginormous help!!

Comment: Also, take a look at `pygame.transform.flip`. You may want to use it isntead of having the images flipped.

Comment: @ThomasLivy If this answered your question, can you mark it as the selected answer so that the question gets flagged as resolved, please.